# Ccuiviewwrapper doesn't allow touch dispatcher to catch touches

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When I use CCUIViewWrapper, I notice that my touch dispatcher doesn't catch any touches, even when the layers that need to have touches are added after the wrappers. Any idea how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like CCUIViewWrapper adds their contained UIViews to the root window as a subview, so essentially the order of things is everything Cocos2d, then any CCUIViewWrappers on top of it.  That explains whey the UIViews are capturing my input even when I add children after the wrappers are added.

It sounds like my best option may be to create any functionality that needs to be done on top of these wrappers within an additional wrapper itself and further add that on top.